# Get the categorie name of Event Organiser plugin

Tags: categories, plugin-event-organiser

How can I get the name of a category in a custom template of the [Event Organiser Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/).

So far the only thing I can get it slug of the category by reading the following variable:

```php
echo $eo_event_loop->query['event-category']; // test-cat
```

From digging a little in standard template the only thing I found is that they use the standard WP function [`single_cat_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/)

```php
echo single_cat_title( '', false );
```

But it doesn't generates any output in the template.

The template based on the following two global variables:

```php
global $eo_event_loop,$eo_event_loop_args;
```

From what I can find in [function reference](http://codex.wp-event-organiser.com/) of the Event Organiser plugin there is not such a function I'm looking for.

Comment: You should ask that at [Stephen Harris](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/9364/stephen-harris) support routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the solution. A view in the mySQL table helped to understand how the **Event Organiser plugin** is using Wordpress. The Event Categories a just normal categories with the taxonomy `event-category`. The only function needed is [`get_term_by()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).

```
// Get term by slug ''test-cat'' in event-category taxonomy.
$cat = get_term_by('slug', $eo_event_loop->query['event-category'], 'event-category');
echo $cat->name; // Output: Test Category
```